# Are the Half-Life 2 Antlions a Starship Troopers reference?

Tags: video-games, inspiration, starship-troopers, half-life

The Antlions in Half-Life 2:

[image: Antlion]

bear a strong resemblance to the Starship Troopers Warrior Bug

[image: Warrior Bug]

Although these pictures don't convey the resemblance very well, especially when in swarms antlions are virtually indistinguishable from Warrior Bugs.

---

I'm aware I am not the first to notice that similarity, but I was unable to find any official sources that indicate an actual influence of the first Starship Troopers film when designing the Game.

Is there any source (e.g. interview, article, ...) that would support this theory?

Comment: Hmm, I had thought Starship Troopers was newer than Half Life. I learned something new today.

Comment: @Xantec: A lot. I'm referring the Half-Life **2**, which came out 2004, seven years after Starship Troopers.

Comment: Yea. Looked it up earlier, SST even came out a year before the original Half Life.

Comment: Evolutionary convergence. There are only so many way an ant-like creature can be designed :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd say no. Much more likely that the HL2 antlions are a reference to real life antlions. These animals are ridiculously cool.

[image: antlion larva]

Comment: What exactly makes them "ridiculously cool"? And what is your speculation based on?

Comment: Both HL2 and [real world Antlions use burrows to trap their prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlion#Sand_pit_traps).  It's worth noting the depiction above is the larval form, the adult form looks more like a spindly dragon fly.  I suspect both Starship Troopers and HL2 used Antlions as inspiration.